# Using external Jars on GWT server-side

Tags: gwt, jar, server-side, xstream

Im new to GWT. Im using the eclipse plugin 
and started tweaking google's 'hello, world!' project: greetServlet.

Im trying to build a webapp that will use XML (de)serializing.
I chose XStream library for the relative easiness.
my classpath includes the xstream.jar.  I also manually copied the jar to the WEB-INF/lib folder 
(Is this a mistake? is there a way in which eclipse will copy external jars by itself to the deployment folder?).

I added a single line to `GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer`
XStream xs = new XStream(); and this is where it fails.

It throws an exception on RPC call to greetServer.
Why? What's the matter?

Is this specific to XStream or am I mising some thing in adding an external jar?

Comment: What exception your serer side is throwing? Can you provide the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in the development mode in eclipse, it could be that XStream is not supported by the Google Appengine whitelist.

http://code.google.com/intl/es-AR/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html

If this is your problem, you can run your application in a Tomcat.